# Does Git generate the content of files in the Working Tree on the fly?

Tags: git

Say I have two files in the repo: a.txt and b.txt.

In branch `hotfix`, I updated b.txt. I commit the change (`C1`).

Then, in branch `master`, I updated a.txt. I commit the change (`C2`).

Then I merge `hotfix` into `master`. The resulting branch merge commit has two parents, pointing to `C1` and `C2`. `C1`'s tree object links to the blob for the updated b.txt. `C2`'s tree object links to the blob for the updated a.txt. There is no single commit that contains a tree pointing to the latest version of a.txt and b.txt.

When `master` is checked out, are the files in the working tree generated on the fly from the different branches?

It is a similar situation when the same file was updated in two branches and subsequently merged successfully. There is no blob object in the database for the final merged version of the file. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you merge into master, the master label is re-hung on the new merge commit, of a tree with the merge results, as with any commit that's a full snapshot. All files.